# Extension of continuous maps to product space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, let $Y$ be a compactification of $X$ and let $f:X \times X \to \mathbb{C}$ denote a continuous map.

If $f(\cdot, x)\in C(Y)$ for every $x\in X$, does it then follow that $f$ admits a continuous extension to $Y\times X$?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean the Alexandroff or one-point compactification $Y=X^*$?
(Also, you probably mean, that $f(-,x)$, which is in $C(X)$ has a continuous extension in $C(Y)$.)

Comment: Tip: Let $f_x:=f(-,x)\colon X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $\hat{f}_x\colon Y\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be its extension for a point $x\in X$, then define $\hat{f}\colon Y\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{C},(y,x)\mapsto f_x(y)$, for which obviously $\hat{f}\vert_{X\times X}=f$ holds. Now why is this map continuous?

Comment: Truly, what I really want is the above to hold true for any compact Hausdorff space $Y$ containing $X$ as a dense subspace (thus, true for any compactification). However, I am unsure if this can be done. Perhaps the Alexandroff reasoning could be helpful in this regard? And yes, that is precisely what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=(0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1]$, define $f:X\times X\to[0,1]$ by $f(t,x)=x^{\frac1t}$.
For each $x$ the limit $\lim_{t\to0}f(t,x)$ exists: it is $0$ if $x<1$ and $1$ if $x=1$.
So each individual $f_x$ has a continuous extension, but the total extension is not continuous at $(0,1)$.

There are many variations on this theme, for example with $X=\mathbb{R}$, the real line, and $Y=\alpha\mathbb{R}$, its one-point compactification.
Consider the function given by $f(x,y)=\exp(-x^2y^2)$.
If one extends $f_y$ to $\bar f_y:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ then $\bar f_0(\infty)=1$ but $\bar f_y(\infty)=0$ if $y\neq0$, so $\bar f$ is not continuous at $(\infty,0)$.

To see what is needed in case $Y=\beta X$ you should work Problem 3.12.21 in Engelking's *General Topology*.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know of a similar counterexample if we assume that $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it to the answer.